# What is the right way to manage image assets for J2ME in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I'm using NetBeans to develop a J2ME app that runs across many different devices.  The app uses a lot of different image assets.  Since the devices have different screen sizes, this means that I need to compile multiple binaries, each with different asset sizes.

So far, I've been using a manual process to control the assets.  I have a directory consisting of a bunch of subdirectories, each corresponding to assets needed for a particular class of device.  For example, I have one directory "320_240", that has assets sized for a 320x240 screen, and another "480_360", that has assets sized for a 480x360 screen.  The files names are exactly the same as is the code that loads them.  Before I compile, I just copy the proper files into the default package (under src).

This can obviously be improved.  I already have different project configurations representing the different screen sizes, so I'd like to make the assets switch automatically, too.  As a relative novice for NetBeans, I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

FWIW, here's the best I've come up with yet:

1. Create asset. packages under src, where LABEL corresponds to the device class (e.g. "320_240", "480_360")
2. Put the images for each class into the proper src/asset/ directory
3. Create a static final String assetDir that gets set to "/asset//" according to the currently selected project config
4. Load the images using Image.creatImage(assetDir + "image.png")
5. For each configuration, only include the necessary asset directory in Project->Build->Sources Filtering (I think this is necessary to avoid storing the unused images in the compiled app, correct?)

This still feels a bit hokey, though.  This has to be a common problem.  Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lot of images, then the size of jar file will be increased. You can't install that jar in some low-end devices.

Just use one image and resize the image according to screen width and screen height.

To resize the image, use the below method.

```
public Image resizeImage(Image src, int screenHeight, int screenWidth) {
        int srcWidth = src.getWidth();

        int srcHeight = src.getHeight();
        Image tmp = Image.createImage(screenWidth, srcHeight);
        Graphics g = tmp.getGraphics();
        int ratio = (srcWidth << 16) / screenWidth;
        int pos = ratio / 2;

        //Horizontal Resize        

        for (int index = 0; index < screenWidth; index++) {
            g.setClip(index, 0, 1, srcHeight);
            g.drawImage(src, index - (pos >> 16), 0);
            pos += ratio;
        }

        Image resizedImage = Image.createImage(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        g = resizedImage.getGraphics();
        ratio = (srcHeight << 16) / screenHeight;
        pos = ratio / 2;

        //Vertical resize

        for (int index = 0; index < screenHeight; index++) {
            g.setClip(0, index, screenWidth, 1);
            g.drawImage(tmp, 0, index - (pos >> 16));
            pos += ratio;
        }
        return resizedImage;

    }
```